# Multi-line tags in Play framework 1.2.4

Tags: java, playframework

I've defined a custom tag in Play 1.2.4 that renders a table something like:

```
*{ in tagTable.html }*

<table>
<tr>
  ${_param1}
</tr>
<tr>
  ${_param2}
</tr>
<tr>
  #{list items: _param3, as: 'item'}
    <td>${item}</td>
  #{/list}
</tr>
</table>
```

But it gives me an error when the call site has the parameters split over multiple lines (each parameter can be somewhat long so I don't want it all on one line).

```
The template /app/views/example.html does not compile : 

illegal colon after argument expression;    solution: a complex label expression before a colon must be parenthesized
```

The call site looks like:

```
#{tagTable
  param1: 'this is some very long content for one line',
  param2: 'this also is some long content',
  param3: ['this', 'is', 'a', 'list', 'also']
/}
```

It works fine if they are on one line.  What is the syntax to allow the tag definition to span lines (or did I pass something else incorrectly?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug that causes an issue on Windows only (in the 1.2.4 version of Play). The bug has actually been fixed, but for the next version of Play 1.2.5.

See https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/107 for more info on the bug.

If you need the bug fixed asap, then you could try downloading the latest master build from github.

Comment: Ah, at least there's a workaround.  I'm new to Play and was a bit surprised something like that didn't work out of the box.  Sounds good.